# Data Object Repository with caching

Tags: entity-framework, repository

I'd like to implement a generic repository on top of EntityFramework. The purpose is to separate DBContext from client side as well as implement additional logic for the repository to manage the source of where objects are coming (Cache,DB).

- ability to flag entity for caсhing (either through annotations, fluent API or just adding it to the list)
- object to be cached on 1st request
- object to be updated (or flagged dirty) if changed and reloaded into cached

Q: I'm sure this must have been done before but I'm having trouble locating good blog or example of cached repository

Answer (score 1):

If you want to a have    **SOME Cache** ==> EF cache(context) ==> Source A.
                         **Same Cache** ==> Provider X    ==> Source B.

Then an option is an MS provided  tool as part of the **Enterprise Library** .  **Application caching Block**

It allows you operate a cache with different features in different modes as is ready for Enterprise use. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664753%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx  (vers5 from may 2011)